# Нахождение комбинаций до того момента, пока не выполнится условие

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

**Вот код, для нахождения комбинаций в массиве**

```
    n = int(input())
    arr = [ int(input()) for i in range(n) ]
    teaMin = int(input())

    sm = sum(arr)
    sums = set()
    sums.add(0)
    # Находим комбинации
    for item in arr:
            for k in range(sm, min(arr) - 1, -1):
                    if (k - item) in sums:
                            sums.add(k)
    print(sums)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он находил комбинации до того момента, пока не найдётся число, которое делится на переменную teaMin без остатка?

Допустим

> [2,3,5]

На выходе должен быть список:

> [2,3,5,7,8,10,12,13,15 ... 32]

Пытался через while, но не смог додумать, как реализовать эту задачу

Comment: "Комбинации" - это в данном случае что?

Comment: в данном коде скорее всего никак, так как вы не знаете верхней границы вложенного цикла - её поиск, собсвтенно, и есть суть задачи.

Comment: @Лерик Ашма Не обязательно на каждый вопрос заводить новый ник ;)

Answer (score 0):

это C#, не Pyton, но идея вроде должна быть понятна

```
void Find(int[] data, int target)
{
    var minValue = data.Min();
    var maxValue = minValue * target;
    var sums = new HashSet<int>();

    sums.Add(0);

    for (var i = minValue; i <= maxValue; i++)
        foreach (var item in data)
            if (sums.Contains(i - item))
            {
                sums.Add(i);
                if (i % target == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {i}");
                    return;
                }
            }   
}
```

для вот такого ввода

```
Find(new[] { 2, 3, 5 }, 16);
```

Оно выдаст

```
Result: 16
```

Так как 16 - это 8 раз по 2, то есть из исходного массива можно составить 16, потому это будет минимальной повторяющейся суммой, которая делится на 16 без остатка.

Comment: Эл-т сам с собой не должен складываться. [2, 3, 5] - [(2 + 3)5, (2+5)7, ((2+3) + 5)10 ... (пока не будет делится на переменную a, которую вводит пользователь)]. Допустим, a = 16, получается, что массив должен закончиться на 32, т.к это минимальное число на которое делится a без остатка.

Comment: @ЛерикАшма как вы собираетесь складывать `[2,3,5]` без повторений, чтобы получть `32`?

Comment: [2,3,5] - [...8, ((2+3)+5)10, (10+2)12, (10+3)13, (10+5)15, 17(15+2), 18(15+3), (15+5)20 ... 32]

Comment: @ЛерикАшма тут `((2+3+5)+5)10` разве 5 не 2 раза присутсвует?

Comment: исправил, случайно написал 5

Comment: @ЛерикАшма вы вот тут `(10+2)12` - 10 получили как `2+3+5`, а дальше прибаляете опять `(10+2)12`? То есть 2 уже дважды используете

Comment: Я вам сэкономлю время, когда у вас массив `2, 3, 5`, то максимальная сумма без повторений = `2+3+5=10`, всё, что больше 10 использует элементы массива больше 1 раза

Comment: Комбинации ищутся до того момента, пока не будет достигнуто какое-либо условие. Эл-т нельзя суммировать с самим собой

Comment: @ЛерикАшма из каких конкретно элементов состоит число 32 в вашем примере в вопросе?